# The BLE advertisement package getting frequency become very low

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

My project need to receive BLE advertisement package,and handle the kCBAdvDataManufacturerData without connecting the BLE device.The BLE device send advertisement package 1 time per second.In an empty viewcontroller ,I receive advertisement package 1 time per second,but in my controller where I display the BLE advertisement package data ,the frequency I receive advertisement package reduce to 1 time/4 sec or lower.In this controller ,I send some http request and update UI using NSTimer 1 time per second.I handle kCBAdvDataManufacturerData in dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0),and update UI in mainqueue .
Anybody have any idea to increase the frequency to receive the BLE advertisement package?

Answer (score 0):

-1. First you need to startDiscovery.

```
-(void)startDiscovery
{
if (self.mBtmanager == nil) {
  _mScanState = false;
    self.mBtmanager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
    self.mBtmanager.delegate = self;
}    
if (self.mBtmanager.state != CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
    _mScanState = true;
}
    NSDictionary *scanOption = @{CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey:@YES};
[self.mBtmanager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:JAALEE_ADV_SERVICE_UUID_STRING], nil] options:scanOption];
}
```

- 2. You need to make connection to Beacon.

```
-(void)startConnectDevice:(CBPeripheral*)peripheral
{
peripheral.delegate = self;
[self.mBtmanager connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];
}
```

-3. Then change the broadcast interval using writeServicesUUID

```
 [peripheral writeValue:value forCharacteristic:characteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
```

-finally CONFIGURE_BROADCAST_INTERVAL_CHARACTERISTIC_ will help you.

Comment: I solved this problem ,thank you for your attention anyway.